# GuessBirthday.java change 1 to Y

Tags: java, eclipse

Alright so I have completely functioning code for my original solution:

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessBirthday {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String set1 =
      " 1  3  5  7\n" +
      " 9 11 13 15\n" +
      "17 19 21 23\n" +
      "25 27 29 31";

String set2 =
  " 2  3  6  7\n" +
  "10 11 14 15\n" +
  "18 19 22 23\n" +
  "26 27 30 31";

String set3 =
  " 4  5  6  7\n" +
  "12 13 14 15\n" +
  "20 21 22 23\n" +
  "28 29 30 31";

String set4 =
  " 8  9 10 11\n" +
  "12 13 14 15\n" +
  "24 25 26 27\n" +
  "28 29 30 31";

String set5 =
  "16 17 18 19\n" +
  "20 21 22 23\n" +
  "24 25 26 27\n" +
  "28 29 30 31";

int day = 0;

// Create a Scanner
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

// Prompt the user to answer questions
System.out.print("Is your birthday in Set1?\n");
System.out.print(set1);
System.out.print("\nEnter N for No and Y for Yes: ");
int answer = input.nextInt();

if (answer == 1)
  day += 1;

// Prompt the user to answer questions
System.out.print("\nIs your birthday in Set2?\n");
System.out.print(set2);
System.out.print("\nEnter 0 for No and 1 for Yes: ");
answer = input.nextInt();

if (answer == 1)
  day += 2;

// Prompt the user to answer questions
System.out.print("Is your birthday in Set3?\n");
System.out.print(set3);
System.out.print("\nEnter 0 for No and 1 for Yes: ");
answer = input.nextInt();

if (answer == 1)
  day += 4;

// Prompt the user to answer questions
System.out.print("\nIs your birthday in Set4?\n");
System.out.print(set4);
System.out.print("\nEnter 0 for No and 1 for Yes: ");
answer = input.nextInt();

if (answer == 1)
  day += 8;

// Prompt the user to answer questions
System.out.print("\nIs your birthday in Set5?\n");
System.out.print(set5);
System.out.print("\nEnter 0 for No and 1 for Yes: ");
answer = input.nextInt();

if (answer == 1)
  day += 16;

System.out.println("\nYour birthday is " + day + "!");
```

}
}

My problem is that I need to change it from 1 to Y and 0 to N but my second solution doesn't work and I'm stumped I'm not really sure what to do I looked all over the internet but no solutions. All I could come up with was this and it doesn't properly function:

```
    package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessBirthday2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String set1 =
      " 1  3  5  7\n" +
      " 9 11 13 15\n" +
      "17 19 21 23\n" +
      "25 27 29 31";

String set2 =
  " 2  3  6  7\n" +
  "10 11 14 15\n" +
  "18 19 22 23\n" +
  "26 27 30 31";

String set3 =
  " 4  5  6  7\n" +
  "12 13 14 15\n" +
  "20 21 22 23\n" +
  "28 29 30 31";

String set4 =
  " 8  9 10 11\n" +
  "12 13 14 15\n" +
  "24 25 26 27\n" +
  "28 29 30 31";

String set5 =
  "16 17 18 19\n" +
  "20 21 22 23\n" +
  "24 25 26 27\n" +
  "28 29 30 31";

int day = 0;

// Create a Scanner
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

// Prompt the user to answer questions
System.out.print("Is your birthday in Set1?\n");
System.out.print(set1);
System.out.print("\nEnter N for No and Y for Yes: ");
char answer = (char) input.nextInt();
System.out.print(answer);
if (answer == 'Y')
  day += 1;

// Prompt the user to answer questions
System.out.print("\nIs your birthday in Set2?\n");
System.out.print(set2);
System.out.print("\nEnter 0 for No and 1 for Yes: ");
answer = (char) input.nextInt();

if (answer == 'Y')
  day += 2;

// Prompt the user to answer questions
System.out.print("Is your birthday in Set3?\n");
System.out.print(set3);
System.out.print("\nEnter 0 for No and 1 for Yes: ");
answer = (char) input.nextInt();

if (answer == 'Y')
  day += 4;

// Prompt the user to answer questions
System.out.print("\nIs your birthday in Set4?\n");
System.out.print(set4);
System.out.print("\nEnter 0 for No and 1 for Yes: ");
answer = (char) input.nextInt();

if (answer == 'Y')
  day += 8;

// Prompt the user to answer questions
System.out.print("\nIs your birthday in Set5?\n");
System.out.print(set5);
System.out.print("\nEnter 0 for No and 1 for Yes: ");
answer = (char) input.nextInt();

if (answer == 'Y')
  day += 16;

System.out.println("\nYour birthday is " + day + "!");
```

}
}

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are expecting characters as input, then you shouldn't be calling `nextInt`.  Call `nextLine` instead, extracting the first character of the input.

```
char answer = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

Then you can compare `answer` to `'Y'` and to `'y'`; if that is `true`, then you can add to `day` as you're currently doing.

Also, your first question asks

```
System.out.print("\nEnter N for No and Y for Yes: ");
```

but the rest of your questions ask:

```
System.out.print("\nEnter 0 for No and 1 for Yes: ");
```

They should be the same each time.

Comment: nextLine requires a return character to accept the entry, Kevin may not want that. Though I'm not entirely sure if next() or nextInt() is any different.

Comment: In my experience, `next()` may read the next token only, but the next token won't appear on the stream until a "Enter" is pressed.  However, `next()` would work well here too, assuming only one word is entered.

Comment: Thanks a lot! such a simple solution solved a lot of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `input.next()` or something. Then `if(answer.equals("Y") || answer.equals("1")`